# Keep getting Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML

Tags: web-part

Keep getting this error "Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer." on a simeple announcements webpart "Listview".

Sort is desc on Modified and Item limit is 2

Saw this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2639184 but the announcement list does not have large sets of data. Please suggest.

Comment: Does SP returns all the data when you have Item Limit configured? Or just the # of records you set in the item Limit section. If its returning all the records then that might be the issue. Is there a way to get the last 2 modified item using filter without messing around with Item Limit?

Comment: I think add a boolean column "ShowOnHomePage" and use filter to display item. So that I can leave item limit section alone.